# Eclipse: find resource on classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, resources, classpath

Is there a way in eclipse to search the classpath for arbitrary resource file names (or patterns)?

I know I can use either

`Navigate > Open Type`

(which will scan the classpath for classes) or

`Navigate > Open Resource`,

which will search for any resource type, but only in my project folders. Is there any way to achieve a combination ob both, to do a resource search (something like `*.xsd`) that searches all jars on the classpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [classpath helper plugin](http://classpathhelper.sourceforge.net/) is at least a starting point. Looks like it doesn't provide a search but it seems to list all entries on the classpath.

I don't know if your fit and willing to modify it but it should provide the basic code to add some filename-based search on top.

Comment: well this is definitely an interesting plugin. I'll certainly have a look at that. Danke :-)

Comment: Keine Ursache & Gruß nach Berlin!

Comment: I'll mark this as the correct answer because I think there is no 100% correct answer out of the box

Answer (score 0):

Which Version are you using?

Because when I open the search-menu (Java-Search), I could choose, which space should be searched, whether the hole workspace or including all JRE-Libraries. Think, it should work for you.

Comment: I use a Galileo distribution, so I am current. java search only searches for types and members (e.g. field names, method names), not resources.

Comment: I mainly meant your version, e.g. 3.5, but maybe it´s not that necessary. Try the "Remote Search" on your Work-Dir with options for "archive files" and "subfolders" on. It lasts a bit long (2-3 min, depends on your work-dir), but the result should fit your expectation. :)

Comment: ok, this is a directory scanner. the problem is: the jars are not in the project dir, they are in my local maven repo (and there are tons of jars in there)

Comment: And there are too many jars, you are not interested in, but also to many interisting jars, that you don´t want to choose them by hand!?

Except for plugins (that I don´t know) the only given thing, which could help you, may be the e.g. File Search, but using a built "Working set", where you could collect all the classes and jars, you want to be searched.
Do you need this searching often?

Comment: yes, I have projects with many dependencies, and they often include an XSD or a properties file somewhere that I'd like to find. obviously I can search them myself (that's what I did in this particular case) but this happens about twice a week and I find it rather annoying to search through 10 - 20 jars manually. but I think there is no solution

Comment: Yes, there is a solution, but we didn´t found it yet. I think, there are even small application, which serve exactly your needs, if there isn´t a fitting eclipse-plugin, which I can´t imagine..