# eclipse search for resource including jar files

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to search for resource "temp.xml" in a project. This resource is in one of the library files of the project.

I can find it manually but when I am trying with ctrl+shift+R I am unable to do it.

Can any one suggest, how to search for resource in a project including libraries.

I am using  Indigo SR1.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to type:

```
Ctrl + h
```

select tab **File Search** and entering file name: good search!

Comment: How do I search within a jar file ?

Comment: does not work for me with eclipse mars to find css in a jar. Maybe this plugin [suggested here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996371/eclipse-find-resource-on-classpath) helps